# Scraping row of info underneath a table header when the html tags for the row are not nested under the header tag

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

I'm trying to scrape a [table](https://wd.kyepsb.net/EPSB.WebApps/KECI/view_data.aspx?id=37161) but I've run into a bit of a snag. I want to make sure that the data underneath each header (ex. `Cert Issued (30)`) is grouped with the corresponding header.

The problem arises when I'm trying to work with the html below.

```
<tr>
                        <td>                        
                            <table class="EPSBResultGrid" cellspacing="0" rules="cols" border="1" style="border-color:DarkGray;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody><tr class="EPSBResultGridHeader">
        <th scope="col">Cred</th><th scope="col">Description</th><th scope="col">Effective</th><th scope="col">Expiration</th><th scope="col">Restricted To</th>
    </tr><tr class="EPSBResultGridHeader">
        <td colspan="9" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-weight:bold;">Do Not Print (00)</td>
    </tr><tr class="EPSBResultGridItem">
        <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_CRED_CODE">RANK1</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_CRED_DESC">Rank I</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl03$EFF_DATE_txtDateMM">07<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" value="07"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl03$EFF_DATE_txtDateDD">01<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" value="01"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl03$EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY">2000<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="2000"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl02" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl03" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl04" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl04" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl03$EXP_DATE_txtDateMM">06<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" value="06"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl03$EXP_DATE_txtDateDD">30<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" value="30"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl03$EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY">2020<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="2020"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl06" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl07" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl08" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl09" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl09" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl03_ORG_NAME"></span></td>
    </tr><tr class="EPSBResultGridHeader">
        <td colspan="9" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-weight:bold;">Cert Issued (30)</td>
    </tr><tr class="EPSBResultGridAlternatingItem">
        <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_CRED_CODE">G20</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_CRED_DESC">Middle School Teaching Field: Social Studies</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl05$EFF_DATE_txtDateMM">07<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" value="07"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl05$EFF_DATE_txtDateDD">01<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" value="01"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl05$EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY">1995<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="1995"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl02" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl04" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl04" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl05$EXP_DATE_txtDateMM">06<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" value="06"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl05$EXP_DATE_txtDateDD">30<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" value="30"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl05$EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY">2020<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="2020"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl06" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl07" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl08" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl09" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl09" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl05_ORG_NAME"></span></td>
    </tr><tr class="EPSBResultGridItem">
        <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_CRED_CODE">G71</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_CRED_DESC">Middle School Teaching Field: Mathematics</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl06$EFF_DATE_txtDateMM">07<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" value="07"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl06$EFF_DATE_txtDateDD">01<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" value="01"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl06$EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY">1995<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="1995"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl01" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl02" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl03" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl04" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl04" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl06$EXP_DATE_txtDateMM">06<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" value="06"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl06$EXP_DATE_txtDateDD">30<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" value="30"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl06$EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY">2020<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="2020"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl06" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl07" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl08" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl09" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ctl09" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl06_ORG_NAME"></span></td>
    </tr><tr class="EPSBResultGridAlternatingItem">
        <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_CRED_CODE">PCS</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_CRED_DESC">Provisional Certificate For Guidance Counselor, Secondary Grades 5-12</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl07$EFF_DATE_txtDateMM">01<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" value="01"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl07$EFF_DATE_txtDateDD">01<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" value="01"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl07$EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY">2016<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="2016"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl01" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl02" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl03" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl04" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl04" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl07$EXP_DATE_txtDateMM">06<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" value="06"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl07$EXP_DATE_txtDateDD">30<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" value="30"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl07$EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY">2020<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="2020"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl06" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl07" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl08" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl09" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ctl09" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl07_ORG_NAME"></span></td>
    </tr><tr class="EPSBResultGridItem">
        <td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_CRED_CODE">PMBF</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_CRED_DESC">Provisional Certificate For Teaching In The Middle Grades 5-8 (And For Other Assignments As Identified By Kentucky Program Of Studies)</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl08$EFF_DATE_txtDateMM">07<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EFF_DATE_txtDateMM" value="07"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl08$EFF_DATE_txtDateDD">01<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EFF_DATE_txtDateDD" value="01"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl08$EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY">2015<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EFF_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="2015"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl01" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl02" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl03" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl04" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl04" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><nobr><span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl08$EXP_DATE_txtDateMM">06<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EXP_DATE_txtDateMM" value="06"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl08$EXP_DATE_txtDateDD">30<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EXP_DATE_txtDateDD" value="30"></span>-<span class="" id="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl08$EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY">2020<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_EXP_DATE_txtDateYYYY" value="2020"></span></nobr><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl06" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a day.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl07" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a month.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl08" style="color:Red;display:none;">You must enter a year.</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl09" evaluationfunction="cb_verifydate_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ctl09" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Invalid Date.</span></td><td><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl08_ORG_NAME"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table><br><span><span>Note: Suspended and revoked credentials are shown with red text with a strike through line.</span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

The the info (`class="EPSBResultGridItem"` & `class="EPSBResultGridAlternatingItem"`) below the headers (`class="EPSBResultHeader"`) are not nested underneath them and as a result I've been having trouble finding a way to make sure that the information under each header is grouped with the correct header.

This is my code:

```
count = 0
header = tree.xpath(
    './/table/tr[@class="EPSBResultGridHeader"]')
difference = 10 - len(header)
for i in range(0, difference):
    header.append('')

for license_row in header:
    count = count + 1

    try:
        header_data = license_row.xpath(".//text()")
        header_data = clean(header_data)

        nested_data = license_row.xpath(".//following-sibling::tr//text()")
        nested_data = clean(nested_data)
        print count, header_data
        print count, nested_data

    except AttributeError:
        header_data = ''

    # Append licensure data
    if count == 1:
        lheader1.append(header_data)
        lheader_info1(nested_data)
    if count == 2:
        lheader2.append(header_data)
        lheader_info2(nested_data)
    if count == 3:
        lheader3.append(header_data)
        lheader_info3(nested_data)
    if count == 4:
        lheader4.append(header_data)
        lheader_info4(nested_data)
    if count == 5:
        lheader5.append(header_data)
        lheader_info5(nested_data)
```

My end goal is to have an output like this:

```
>>>print lheader_info2
['RANK1', 'Rank I', '07-01-2018', '06-30-2021']

>>>print lheader_info3
['G20', 'Middle School Teaching Field: Social Studies----', 'G30', 'Middle School Teaching Field: English And Communications----', 'ILE2', 'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership -- Early Elementary School Principal, Grades K-4; Level II', '07-01-2017', '06-30-2021', 'ILM2', 'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Middle Grade School Principal, Grades 5-8; Level II', '07-01-2017', '06-30-2021', 'ILV2', 'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Supervisor Of Instruction, Grades K-12; Level II', '07-01-2018', '06-30-2021', 'PMBF', 'Provisional Certificate For Teaching In The Middle Grades 5-8 (And For Other Assignments As Identified By Kentucky Program Of Studies)', '07-01-2016', '06-30-2021']
```

I'm using `lxml` but I've also used `BeautifulSoup` if that seems like a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would locate every subheader and iterate over the [next `tr` siblings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) breaking the loop once another header is met, or reached the end of the table:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://wd.kyepsb.net/EPSB.WebApps/KECI/view_data.aspx?id=37161"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

data = defaultdict(list)

table = soup.find("table", class_="EPSBResultGrid")
for header in table.select("tr.EPSBResultGridHeader")[1:]:
    header_name = header.get_text(strip=True)
    for row in header.find_next_siblings("tr"):
        if "EPSBResultGridHeader" in row.get("class", []):
            break

        data[header_name].append(row.td.get_text(strip=True))

pprint(dict(data))
```

Prints:

```
{'Cert Issued (30)': ['G20', 'G30', 'ILE2', 'ILM2', 'ILV2', 'PMBF'],
 'Do Not Print (00)': ['RANK1'],
 'History (97)': ['ILE2', 'ILM2', 'ILV2', 'RANK1']}
```

The `[1:]` slice here is to skip the initial top-level table header.

Comment: I think you want `data[header_name].extend([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all("td")])`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham for all the cells, yeah, just wanted to give the sample of how to "group" the rows mostly. Thanks!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I was hesitant to name either one of your answers as the accepted answer, since they both are excellent but I ended up using alecxe's. I learned more trying to understand both of your answers than I did fiddling around with my code for over a week. Thanks again!

Comment: @alecxe I have a follow-up question. In the line `if "EPSBResultGridHeader" in row.get("class", []):`, what purpose is `row.get("class", [])` serving? I would've just put `row` but that doesn't yield the same output and I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: @otteheng sure, elements in beautifulsoup have a dictionary-like access to its attributes. The `get()` method is a safe way to get an attribute and, if it does not exist, provide a default value - so, if there is no `class` attribute, we get an empty list which helps to avoid any related errors. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2):

using *lxml*

```
def pair():
    tree = html.fromstring(requests.get(url).content)
    # get table and iterate over the trs
    iter_trs = tree.cssselect("table.EPSBResultGrid")[0].iter("tr")
    # skip the initial tr
    next(iter_trs)
    # first EPSBResultGridHeader
    start = next(iter_trs).xpath("td//text()")[0]
    nodes, tmp = {}, []
    # iterate over the rest of the nodes
    for node in iter_trs:
        # if we find another EPSBResultGridHeader, yield what we have and start again.
        if node.get("class") == "EPSBResultGridHeader":
            nodes[start] = tmp
            start, tmp = node.xpath("td//text()")[0], []
        else:
            tmp.append([td.xpath("normalize-space(.)").replace(ur"\xa0", "") for td in node.xpath("./td")])
    return nodes
```

Which would give you:

```
{'Cert Issued (30)': [[u'G20',
                       u'Middle School Teaching Field: Social Studies',
                       u'--',
                       u'--',
                       u''],
                      [u'G30',
                       u'Middle School Teaching Field: English And Communications',
                       u'--',
                       u'--',
                       u''],
                      [u'ILE2',
                       u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership -- Early Elementary School Principal, Grades K-4; Level II',
                       u'07-01-2017',
                       u'06-30-2021',
                       u''],
                      [u'ILM2',
                       u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Middle Grade School Principal, Grades 5-8; Level II',
                       u'07-01-2017',
                       u'06-30-2021',
                       u''],
                      [u'ILV2',
                       u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Supervisor Of Instruction, Grades K-12; Level II',
                       u'07-01-2018',
                       u'06-30-2021',
                       u''],
                      [u'PMBF',
                       u'Provisional Certificate For Teaching In The Middle Grades 5-8 (And For Other Assignments As Identified By Kentucky Program Of Studies)',
                       u'07-01-2016',
                       u'06-30-2021',
                       u'']],
 'Do Not Print (00)': [[u'RANK1',
                        u'Rank I',
                        u'07-01-2018',
                        u'06-30-2021',
                        u'']],
 'History (97)': [[u'ILE2',
                   u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership -- Early Elementary School Principal, Grades K-4; Level II',
                   u'07-01-2012',
                   u'06-30-2017',
                   u''],
                  [u'ILM2',
                   u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Middle Grade School Principal, Grades 5-8; Level II',
                   u'07-01-2012',
                   u'06-30-2017',
                   u''],
                  [u'ILV2',
                   u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Supervisor Of Instruction, Grades K-12; Level II',
                   u'07-01-2013',
                   u'06-30-2018',
                   u''],
                  [u'RANK1', u'Rank I', u'12-15-1995', u'06-30-2018', u'']]}
```

If you want flat lists use extend `tmp.extend(td.xpath("normalize-space(.)").replace(u"\xa0", "") for td in node.xpath("./td")):`

```
{'Cert Issued (30)': [u'G20',
                      u'Middle School Teaching Field: Social Studies',
                      u'--',
                      u'--',
                      u'',
                      u'G30',
                      u'Middle School Teaching Field: English And Communications',
                      u'--',
                      u'--',
                      u'',
                      u'ILE2',
                      u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership -- Early Elementary School Principal, Grades K-4; Level II',
                      u'07-01-2017',
                      u'06-30-2021',
                      u'',
                      u'ILM2',
                      u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Middle Grade School Principal, Grades 5-8; Level II',
                      u'07-01-2017',
                      u'06-30-2021',
                      u'',
                      u'ILV2',
                      u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Supervisor Of Instruction, Grades K-12; Level II',
                      u'07-01-2018',
                      u'06-30-2021',
                      u'',
                      u'PMBF',
                      u'Provisional Certificate For Teaching In The Middle Grades 5-8 (And For Other Assignments As Identified By Kentucky Program Of Studies)',
                      u'07-01-2016',
                      u'06-30-2021',
                      u''],
 'Do Not Print (00)': [u'RANK1', u'Rank I', u'07-01-2018', u'06-30-2021', u''],
 'History (97)': [u'ILE2',
                  u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership -- Early Elementary School Principal, Grades K-4; Level II',
                  u'07-01-2012',
                  u'06-30-2017',
                  u'',
                  u'ILM2',
                  u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Middle Grade School Principal, Grades 5-8; Level II',
                  u'07-01-2012',
                  u'06-30-2017',
                  u'',
                  u'ILV2',
                  u'Professional Certificate For Instructional Leadership--Supervisor Of Instruction, Grades K-12; Level II',
                  u'07-01-2013',
                  u'06-30-2018',
                  u'',
                  u'RANK1',
                  u'Rank I',
                  u'12-15-1995',
                  u'06-30-2018',
                  u'']}
```